# ValueError: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['input_shape'])) while loading model

Tags: 3d, python-3.6, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am using google colab where to use free gpu, tensorflow 2.0 is needed.Input layer contains 4 tuples channel which is multiple 3d images.I called a function :

```
    input_shape= input_shape=(4,96,96,96)
    model = build_model(input_shape=input_shape, output_channels=3)


   def build_model(input_shape=(4, 96,96,96), output_channels=3, weight_L2=0.1, weight_KL=0.1):
    ## Input Layer
   inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=[4,96,96,96],name='inp')
    ## The Initial Block
   x =  tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(
   filters=32,
   kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
   strides=1,
   padding='same',
   data_format='channels_first',
   name='Input_x1')(inp)

   ## Dropout (0.2)
   x =  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)

   ## Green Block x1 (output filters = 32)
   x1 = tf.green_block(x, tf.constant(32), name='x1')
   x =  tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(
   filters=32,
   kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
   strides=2,
   padding='same',
   data_format='channels_first',
   name='Enc_DownSample_32')(x1)
```

I got following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-6468460baa07> in <module>()
     
---> 89 model = build_model(input_shape=input_shape, output_channels=3)
         90 
     91 model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=1, epochs=100)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_size, name, dtype, sparse, tensor, ragged, **kwargs)
    
    286   if kwargs:
--> 287     raise ValueError('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', kwargs.keys())
    288
    289   if shape is None and tensor is None:

ValueError: ('Unrecognized keyword arguments:', dict_keys(['input_shape']))
```